# What kind of memory does VirtualAlloc/Ex allocate

Tags: c++, memory-management, win32-process

I know that C/C++ style programs have memory sections, the stack, heap, .text, etc. But when I use VirtualAlloc, from where does it allocate memory? I don’t think it’s the heap because I can just use HeapAlloc.

Advice would be appreciated!

Comment: In the virtual address space, which is why it starts with *virtual*. See the [VirtualAlloc documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thank you! One last thing. If I were to allocate a large amount of memory to store a data file, should I use VirtualAlloc or should I use the heap instead?

Comment: Very large == virtual. It's virtually (pun intended) unlimited on modern OSes (including Windows).

Comment: Lol alright thanks!

Comment: On Windows, all memory in a process is Virtual memory.  In C++, stack (automatic) and heap (dynamic) memory are just subsets of a process's Virtual memory. See [Thread Stack Size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686774.aspx), [Comparing Memory Allocation Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366533.aspx), and [Managing Virtual Memory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810627.aspx) on MSDN for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heap memory resides in your programs virtual memory that is allocated by VirtualAlloc behind the scenes. However, the problem is that VirtualAlloc allocates memory only in large chunks called pages, which would make it infeasible to use for general memory allocation.

For this reason there is HeapAlloc which manages allocated pages and can concatenate multiple allocations into one page so that you don't unnecessarilly allocate a whole page (usually 4KB, but this is not a rule) for every small allocation.

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct:

> I know that C/C++ style programs have memory sections, the stack, heap, .text, etc.

Such sections exits only through linking on system system and through loading on other systems. Sections in this context only tell how parts of the application are to be grouped in memory. When your program runs it just has memory.

A function like VirtualAlloc simply allocates pages to the process.